# Insert urls on content body

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there any way to insert path to images or links on a content without hard coding it? Our development environment and our production environement have different base paths so the base path of the images and links must not be hard coded.

Comment: Sorry for my english but what do you want to do exactly? I dont understand the question. You want insert in content body any links without ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Pathologic](http://drupal.org/project/pathologic) module to help with this. Excerpt from the documentation...

Rule Order

Note that the order in which you include the rules may be important. In a scenario with three servers (for example, development on http://local.example.com/drupal, testing on http://example.com/drupal, and production on http://example.com) and using a WYSIWYG editor (as noted below), the following rules (paths to be matched) will work in order:

http://local.example.com/drupal/
http://local.example.com/
http://example.com/drupal/
http://example.com/
/drupal/
/

Pathologic works by stripping out the path as defined above and ensuring that what remains will work as a path relative to the site's $base_url (the URL you see in the location bar when looking at your  page), no matter which server it is on. It works down the list in order and only applies the first rule that matches a given link. Placing http://local.example.com first in the list, for instance, will rewrite http://local.example.com/drupal/about as /drupal/about, and this will NOT be rewritten further by the /drupal/ rule, so all possible permutations should be included in order of deepest to shallowest matching path. Some of the example rules may not be necessary for your situation, but it is safe to include even unlikely paths that you would like corrected (removed).

Now sit back and enjoy the fruits of Pathologic’s labor."